# To identify second mouse click on the same cell within the grid

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, onclick

i want to place an image inside the cell on the first click and another image on the second click at the same position. In order to do that i tried writing onclick function in the  tag..but as its written within functions it wont work..is there any other way to achieve the need ? plz help?

JS for placing the images on click:-

```
function changeColor1(elem)
{ 
     elem.innerHTML = '<img src="images/atom1.png" width="20px" height="20px" onclick=changecolor2(this) />';   
    //alert("Row Index is:"+elem.parentNode.rowIndex+elem.cellIndex);
    var x= elem.cellIndex;
    var y= elem.parentNode.rowIndex;
    click_count(x,y);
 }
 function changeColor2(elem)
{ 
     elem.innerHTML = '<img src="images/2circles.png" width="20px" height="20px" onclick=changecolor3(this) />';    
    //alert("Row Index is:"+elem.parentNode.rowIndex+elem.cellIndex);
    var x= elem.cellIndex;
    var y= elem.parentNode.rowIndex;
    click_count(x,y);
 }
```

code for making the grid:

```
$rows = 7; // define number of rows
$cols = 6;// define number of columns
echo "<center>";
echo "<table border='1'   cellspacing=0 cellpadding='35' pixels'>";

for($tr=0;$tr<$rows;$tr++){

    echo "<tr>";
        for($td=0;$td<$cols;$td++){
               echo "<td onclick=\"changeColor1(this)\" >&nbsp &nbsp</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Hi, try to use toggle function of jquery.

Comment: i need to identify 4 mouse clicks at the same position with different functions..is there a way for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function hasClass(element, cls) {
return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}

function changeColor2(elem)
{ 
 if(!hasClass(elem, 'clicked')){
  //clicked first time 
   elem.className = elem.className + " clicked";//add clicked class to element on first click
   elem.innerHTML = '<img src="images/2circles.png" width="20px" height="20px"    onclick=changecolor3(this) />';    
  //alert("Row Index is:"+elem.parentNode.rowIndex+elem.cellIndex);
  var x= elem.cellIndex;
  var y= elem.parentNode.rowIndex;
  click_count(x,y);}
else{
    //clicked second time and onward
  }
}
```

Comment: can u please explain hasClass functionality..?

Comment: Hasclass function checks whether element(passed as parameter element) contains the class(passed as parameter cls)

Comment: where am i suppose it add the hasClass function call...am i supposed it write it while calling the 1st time..i.e. in the <td> tag? for eg:- <td onclick=\"changeColor1(this)\" >&nbsp &nbsp</td>"; instead of writing this am i supposed to write       <td onclick=\" hasClass(this)\" >&nbsp &nbsp</td>";

Comment: I have added the code in changeColor2 which will add class clicked on first click. the else part in the function is second and afterword clicks.

Comment: how can i add my 3rd and 4th click functionality ?  i am not able to change images on my 3rd and 4th click with jst writing else..so wat condition can i use ?

Comment: you need to set global integer variable(`var clickedcount=0;`). you need to increment it on each click. and then check when `clickedcount==3 or 4`. and then change src accordingly